# Mercurial repo too large, can't connect, clone

Tags: git, mercurial, atlassian-sourcetree

Our BitBucket repo has grown to over 3 gigs and now when I try to clone in SourceTree all I get is the trying to connect symbol. When I try in Tortoise it clones to a certain point then disconnects saying it expected # bytes but got #.

I can't download the .zip from BitBucket because it's too large. What can I do to clone?

Comment: I ran into this problem using TeamCity and TortoiseHg. I got the message that Brad mentions. I didn't really want to do a partial pull to fix the issue in case TC ever dropped the folder and tried to re-pull. I was able to get around the issue by switching to SSH though that had its own issues. My repo was less than 500 MB but it was this symptom. Maybe something else was causing it to timeout but it was pretty irritating esp with a repo I didn't think was all that massive.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Clone to an old revision, using `hg clone -r <revision>`, and pull the rest. You can also pull progressively, if necessary.

Comment: I'm only familiar with Sourcetree, how do I run terminal commands? Do I need to install something else?

Comment: I do not know SourceTree, but it might be an option you can set when cloning. Otherwise, check this link: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/54473/how-do-i-use-command-line-tools

Answer (score 7):

I also experienced this problem with a very large, multi-gigabyte repository that was stored on BitBucket. If I tried to simply clone the entire repo, it would always abort in the middle of "adding file changes". If you're using TortoiseHG the error message resembles "abort: stream ended unexpectedly (got ##### bytes, expected ######)"

The solution is to "get the party started" by only cloning the first few hundred check-ins, and then progressively downloading more revisions using the Mercurial `pull` command.

Here's the command line:

```
hg clone -r 500 https://Someone@bitbucket.org/MyCompany/MyRepoName MyDevFolder
```

This will clone the first 500 revisions (`-r 500`) of the repository named `MyRepoName`, and then copy them into a new folder named `MyDevFolder`. (You can, of course, omit the "MyDevFolder" and it will simply create a new folder based on the name of your repository)

If the above is successful, change into your new development folder and try to progressively update to higher revision numbers.

```
cd MyDevFolder
hg pull -r 1000
hg pull -r 2000
hg pull -r 3000
...
hg pull -r [Whatever the maximum number of revisions is]
hg pull
hg update
```

As a precaution, near the end of the process you should issue a simple `hg pull` to ensure that you have pulled all of the code in its entirety.

The `hg update` will, of course, update the files in your `MyDevFolder` to reflect the most recent version available of the source code.

Comment: Thats the error that I got. Thanks for the heads up.