# hgwatchman throws warning when trying to clone

Tags: mercurial, mercurial-extension

I installed "watchman" and "hgwatchman" in my linux box. Configured them following the https://bitbucket.org/facebook/hgwatchman link.

When I tried to clone a hg repo, I get the below warning:

```
warning: watchman unavailable: watchman socket discovery error: "A non-recoverable condition has triggered.  Watchman needs your help!
The triggering condition was at timestamp=1408431707: inotify-add-watch(/home/prabhugs/work/sw/.hg/store/data/export/types) -> No space left on device
All requests will continue to fail with this message until you resolve
the underlying problem.  You will find more information on fixing this at
https://facebook.github.io/watchman/troubleshooting.html#poison-inotify-add-watch
"
```

My hgrc file is like,

```
[extensions]
hgwatchman = /path/to/hgwatchman

[watchman]
mode = {off, on, paraoid}
```

There is enough space in the disk

please help to overcome this warning.

Comment: You can try this solution, just to remove the disk space uncertainty: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24466958/mercurial-repo-too-large-cant-connect-clone

Comment: Thanks Vince, that did not help me :(
I get this error quite often. But it goes off if I restart my laptop. Whenever I do a huge hg operation (in GiBs), I get this error back.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the instructions in the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/troubleshooting.html#poison-inotify-add-watch).

For reference:

> If you've encountered this state it means that your kernel was unable
>   to watch a dir in one or more of the roots you've asked it to watch.
>   This particular condition is considered non-recoverable by Watchman on
>   the basis that nothing that the Watchman service can do can guarantee
>   that the root cause is resolved, and while the system is in this
>   state, Watchman cannot guarantee that it can respond with the correct
>   results that its clients depend upon. We consider ourselves poisoned
>   and will fail all requests for all watches (not just the watch that it
>   triggered on) until the process is restarted.
>
> There are two primary reasons that this can trigger:
>
> - The user limit on the total number of inotify watches was reached or the kernel failed to allocate a needed resource
> - Insufficient kernel memory was available
>
> The resolution for the former is to revisit [System Specific
>   Preparation Documentation](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/install.html#system-specific-preparation) and raise your limits accordingly.
>
> The latter condition implies that your workload is exceeding the
>   available RAM on the machine. It is difficult to give specific advice
>   to resolve this condition here; you may be able to tune down other
>   system limits to free up some resources, or you may just need to
>   install more RAM in the system.